PhpWord Samples Manual Install
The documentation for Manual Install is out of date. I tried to manually write an Autoloader class and maybe it worked? but the only output I get in Sample-01.php is 02:56:03 Create new PhpWord object
Of course that's before I tried putting in Sample_footer and Sample_header. Once I add those the server just gives Error 500
I tried checking logs and modifying error_reporting, display_errors, error.log, E_ALL, absolutely nothing happens when I do tail -f  and try to load that page
references: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord
Manual Install: https://phpoffice.github.io/PHPWord/install.html
I'm highly perplexed. Unfortunately it's the end of the day so I'll check back in tomorrow. And yes, the github says to use StackOverflow.
Update:
I have modified bootstrap.php file and created PhpWord/src/Autoloader.php, and Installed PHP Extensions using command line. After all of these fixes, Samples 01 to 03 work almost perfectly now (they say PDF failed but the rest works). Sample 04 gives no error or output. Still no logs.
I'm a bit unsure if copying the vendor folder over to the targer server will work as without SSH i might not be able to use PHP Extensions. It will be a learning experience, I guess.
I am mirroring the post I made on issue #2543
Made an attempt helped by documentation, reddit, stackoverflow and chatgpt. Structure of directories is assumed to place our source code in /lib/PhpOffice/PhpWord, samples at /samples, Autoloader.php at  /lib/PhpOffice/PhpWord/, modified bootstrap.php. Note that I only got Sample_01 through Sample_03 working and may have made other changes that I forgot about. PDF shows as failed but the docx/html seem to work.
Did not test anything besides Sample_01 to Sample_04, haven't tried actually writing code or running real tests, sorry. Hopefully this serves as a base, idk
./
├── ./lib
│   └── ./lib/PhpOffice
│       ├── ./lib/PhpOffice/Common
│       ├── ./lib/PhpOffice/PhpWord
│       └── ./lib/PhpOffice/PHPWord
└── ./samples
    ├── ./samples/bootstrap
    │   ├── ./samples/bootstrap/css
    │   ├── ./samples/bootstrap/fonts
    │   └── ./samples/bootstrap/js
    ├── ./samples/resources
    └── ./samples/results
...

https://pastebin.com/SKMWn9VN <-- added ./lib/PhpOffice/PhpWord/Autoloader.php
<?php

namespace PhpOffice\PhpWord;

/**
 * Custom Autoloader for PHPWord
 */
class Autoloader
{
    const BASE_DIR = __DIR__;

    /**
     * Register the autoloader
     */
    public static function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register([new self, 'autoload']);
    }

    /**
     * Autoload function
     */
    public static function autoload($class)
    {
        $prefix = "PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\";
        $baseDir = self::BASE_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

        if (strpos($class, $prefix) !== 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $relativeClass = substr($class, strlen($prefix));
        $file = $baseDir . str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $relativeClass) . ".php";

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require_once $file;
        } else {
            die("Class $class not found in $file");
        }
    }
}

https://pastebin.com/Yn23zEXi <-- modified ./bootstrap.php
<?php
$phpWordPath = realpath(__DIR__ . '/lib/PhpOffice/PhpWord');

if (file_exists($phpWordPath . '/Autoloader.php')) {
    require_once $phpWordPath . '/Autoloader.php';

    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();
} else {
    throw new Exception(
        sprintf(
            "Could not find the PHPWord autoloader at '%s'. Please check your file paths.",
            $phpWordPath . '/Autoloader.php'
        )
    );
}
?>

Edit 2
Log error writes were being blocked by SELinux, setting it to 0 (permissive mode) did prove it was blocking it because log error writes worked.. anyone doing this in the future might want to double check their SELinux is actually configured correctly and that the log folder has the correct SELinux permissions. Refer to Red Hat Linux 8 Enterprise - SELinux States and Modes

Please tell us your dev environment: System OS, Php version, etc

Oracle cloud instance - Oracle Linux 8, Apache 2, PHP 8.2.25. I opened firewall and SELinux rule so that I can execute PHP.  php.ini has set error_reporting = E_ALL; display_errors = On; error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log. I thought it could be permissions or owner issue so i set sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html, still not working.
I'm going to double check that I didn't mix up my file structure now.

What is your question? Something like: "How can I install PHPWord manually?"?
To answer this kind of question
I looked into the related repo on GitHub. Nothing about a manual installation. On the installation section of the readMe we have: "PHPWord is installed via Composer.". To use composer seems to be the only possibility nowadays. When using composer, the shown example in the same section should be valid.
You could still do it by your own. But then you must download all dependencies, place the files in a reasonable structure and implement a correct working autoloader.
Find the dependencies
Looking into composer.json of PHPWord the only dependency is phpoffice/math. This lib, in turn, has no dependencies. (the old dependency was phpoffice/common, see the links from the second link of OP)
Place the files in a reasonable structure

In root of your project add a folder e.g. phpoffice or vendor/phpoffice.
In this new folder create new folders: e.g. phpword and math.
Download the whole PHPWord repo and place the content into phpword folder.
Download the whole Math repo and place the content into math folder.

Implement a correct working autoloader
How to create an autoloader can be found e.g. here:
how does php autoloader works

Make sure you find out, where the error was logged. When you fix your project according my description above and still have errors, then probably we can't help you anymore without the error log.

Manual Installation can be found from the github page in the about section on the right, that takes you to https://phpoffice.github.io/PHPWord/, then click install in the left navbar, you'll see Manual Installation after install using Composer.
But thank you for looking into it, I will try what you said.
